# HTML Strange colored box in corner of image links

Tags: html, css, image, colors, icons

I've been having this very slight issue when creating links through icons and images. I often get these strange colored boxes in the bottom right corner.

[Example one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrZTn.png)

[Example two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcwig.png)

After playing around with it a little bit, I noticed that the color of the box changes with my a{} tag in my CSS file. Additionally, it becomes purple after I click it as it was a link. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code for the link:

```
<a href="https://github.com/blah">
    <i class="fa fa-github fa-5x"></i>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  color: #403739; }
a:hover {
  color: #362E30; }
```

Comment: Do you have any code to replicate the problem?

Comment: It's the `<a>`'s underline, no?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the code, updated

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
#footer a {
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```